# Give a second life to a 18650 battery cell, which has 0.1 V?

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have a 7.4V battery pack consisting of 2 x 18650 cells.

- One of them has 3.4 V, so I tried to charge it with a [good old TP4056 board](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf), and it worked:

  [image]
- **The second 18650 cell seems nearly dead with ~ 0.1V**. When I connect the TP4056 charging board, it doesn't seem to charge (blue light: full).

Is there a way to give an initial "boost" to a dying 18650 cell, to bring it to 2.5 V, so that eventually a TP4056 charging board will recover it?

Comment: They say there is a risk of short circuit if charging a cell which was abused in this way. The ~0V cell is already damaged. That's why the charger intentionally rejects it. https://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?344213-Is-there-any-danger-to-charging-zero-voltage-Lithium-Ions

Comment: Second life ... as a firework?

Comment: You can *try*, but please do it in a metal container in a well-ventilated area because it will probably explode.

Comment: 0V is not nearly dead. 3V is nearly dead.